# fullcalendar rerender dayrender function ondemand

Tags: javascript, meteor, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar in meteor

here is how my `dayRender` looks like

```
    dayRender: function (date, cell) {
            if(data && data.available && data.available.length > 0){
              ..........
              var res = moment(a).isSame(b, 'day');
              if( res){
                cell.css("background-color","rgb(175, 207, 236)");
              }
            }
      });

    },
```

Initially I'm getting dates from server and I'm displaying background for the dates I want.

After I got the updated dates from server I want to add background colors to those dates,

Is there any way to update background colors for those new dates that I received from db.

Some function like `reRenderDayRender` so I can add background color to new dates.

I tried calendar `refresh` function it is not working and I tried to `destroy` and then `render` functions which is also not working.

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question, it's very hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Joum thanks for the feedback, I updated question, let me know it makes any sense or not.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change background color on new events that were added to the calendar after the first render?

Comment: yes here I'm not bothering about events, I want to add background color dynamically to a date and be able to remove it.

Comment: maybe you should start by posting your current code to better visualize what you mean and need help... maybe on jsbin / jsfiddle / plunker...